# Share A List Across two IActionresult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

Below is my code

```
private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment env;
    private readonly IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor;
    private utility util;

    public GeneratePDFController(IConfiguration _configuration, IHostingEnvironment _env, IActionContextAccessor _actionContextAccessor)
    {
        configuration = _configuration;
        env = _env;
        actionContextAccessor = _actionContextAccessor;
        util = new utility(_configuration, _env);
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IndusIndVM model = new IndusIndVM();
        try
        {
            util.DeleteFolders();
            util.CreateFolders(HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserID"));
            model.BranchList = GetBranchWiseList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["Msg"] = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    public IActionResult GetMemberList(string BranchCode)
    {
        IndusIndVM model = new IndusIndVM();
        try
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(
                            () => { model.BranchList = GetBranchWiseList(); },
                            () => { if (BranchCode != null) { model.MemberList = GetMemberWiseList(BranchCode); } }
                        );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["Msg"] = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            TempData["BranchCode"] = BranchCode;
        }
        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

In Index IActionResult  I am calling a method GetBranchWiseList() which take around 30 seconds to run and in GetMemberList IActionResult  again I want same data so have to run this method again

So here now instead of running this method again in GetMemberList()
I want to store this in a global list

This will give me one benefit ,list will be populated once in Index() and no need to get it again from database in GetMemberList() (will share global list in both Action Method)

For this I declared a global list

```
 private List<PendingListBranchWise> BL;
```

and in constructor

```
 BL = new List<PendingListBranchWise>();
```

And in Index() store list into it

```
 model.BranchList = GetBranchWiseList();
 BL = model.BranchList;
```

Now in GetMemberList()

```
 model.BranchList = BL;
```

But BL is null here , I tried making this list is static too , but its value is null for GetMemberList() , Storing in TempData is not a good option either

How can I retain this list and use it across ActionMethods ?

Comment: Make BL static?

Comment: You asking or suggesting ?

Comment: Suggesting. But you should consider the downsides of using static on a web solution

Comment: I tried static list , but across IActionresult , its null , maybe its different in .Net core

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this:
1. Use [OutputCache(--)]  Attribute for Index method so instead of calling it every time, 
   it will return the cached result.
2. Store the list in the application session.
3. store this list in a global variable.

Comment: Can not use OutputCache as no of record changes everytime Index() get called , I am using Global List , bit don't know how it will affect the performance ,

Comment: It will consume your application memory if you use a Global variable but it will certainly improve performance as you are not hitting database frequently. One more thing you can try is To Create an index-view in the database for fetching this record.

Comment: Thanks , Memory is not a big concern here as I am using it at only one place , but It does solved the problem , processing fast

Comment: And I got another way to do so by writing this data in a file in JSON format